# Keep WebProtege ontology sync'ed with GitHub?

Tags: git, ubuntu, tomcat, ontology, protege

*My question relates to making sure that the latest version of an ontology file is always visible to my collaborators, via multiple web server processes, especially [WebProtege](https://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/WebProtege), running under Tomcat.*

I have an ontology, as an RDF/XML file, in a GitHub repo.  Let's call it `ontologyFolder/MarksOntology.owl`.  I have the repo mirrored on my server `OntoServer.net`.  That means I can symlink `ontologyFolder/` as `/var/www/html/ontologyFolder` and people can see the latest version of my ontology at `http://OntoServer.net/ontologyFolder/MarksOntology.owl`

I have WebProtege running under Tomcat at `http://OntoServer.net:8080/webprotege-2.6.0`.  The webapp home is `/opt/tomcat/webapps/webprotege-2.6.0`

I have created ontology projects in my WebProtege, by uploading an ontology file from my laptop, but **I can't figure where the .owl files belonging to the WebProtege projects live.**

If I do the following, I see my ontology file under `ontologyFolder/`, but nowhere else.

> sudo find / -name "MarksOntology.owl"

***How can I keep an Ontology in a WebProtege project in sync with a `.owl` file being managed by git?***

I remember now that I used the `webprotege.properties` file to do my [configuration](https://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/WebProtegeAdminGuide) . My data directory is `/data/webprotege`, but I don't see anything in there that makes say "aha!"